# Xcode codecompletion, just variables

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I am learing programming and using Xcode. I would like to trim the autocompletion a bit. I feel like this make me not remember syntax, I often just look it up in codecompletion. And I would for the time being be able to hardcode everything.

Is there a way to make it only complete variable names? This is useful for saving time. But i do not want all the extra.
I am programming in c++ for the record.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can press escape key when you want to complete names. The first word in the suggest list always the true word. then you just press Enter/return key.